# Loop and Animate based on Radio Button click

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code which works fine and rotates the div after every 3 seconds

```
var $elements = $('#One, #Two, #Three, #Four');
function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
anim_loop(0);
```

How can I control the loop if I were to do it via radio buttons.

See this example http://jsfiddle.net/w5YHY/1/

I want that the loop should continue but when I click the 3rd radio, the third element #three should show and loop should continue from four. Similarly clicking on 1st radio, #One should show and loop should begin from 2nd element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a click event to stop your loop and restart it with a new index based on the radio you select.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/x4Wd9/2/)

First i set your timeout to a variable so i could clear it on the click event.

```
var animLoop; // declared outside the function

animLoop = setTimeout(function() { // set in the function
```

I changed the following line.

```
$self.fadeOut(1000);
```

To this to make sure the div's fadeout correctly when calling the new loop.

```
$("div").fadeOut(1000);
```

Then in the click event for the radio's i get the id of the radio which i set to correspond to the correct index of the div's and pass it into the new anim_loop.
Hope this is what you were looking for.

below is the code based on your fiddle.

```
    var $elements = $('#One, #Two, #Three, #Four');
var animLoop;
function anim_loop(index) {
    $elements.eq(index).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $("#"+(index)).prop("checked", true);
        animLoop = setTimeout(function() {
            $("div").fadeOut(1000);
            //$self.fadeOut(1000);
            anim_loop((index + 1) % $elements.length);
            $("input").prop("checked", false);
            $("#"+(index +1)).prop("checked", true);
        }, 3000);
    });
}

anim_loop(0); // start with the first element
$("input").click(function()
{
  $("div").fadeOut();
  clearTimeout(animLoop);
  anim_loop(parseFloat($(this).attr("id")));    
});
```

Comment: I had a query. The radio manipulates the loop. How do I it the other way round? Select radio as the loop progresses. So if loop is pos 2, select 2nd radio and so on

Comment: You can do something like this in your loop $("#"+(index +1)).prop("checked", true);  I'll update the code in my post and the fiddle.